# App get crashes with error /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+416)

Tags: android

One of my app uploaded on *play store* and I have found the below error on Crash/ANR page.  In the meantime, I could not understand what the code is saying and at which line get happened. Also, I am new in android. Anyone help me to solve this issue. Also, is it effect our app security feature. Herein the error report:

```
native: pc 0000000000021ae8  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  native: pc 000000000000f0ac  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  native: pc 000000000000f10c  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  native: pc 000000000004d7e3  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  native: pc 000000000004e8e5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+416)
  native: pc 000000000000105b  /system/bin/app_process
  native: pc 000000000000e533  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
  native: pc 0000000000000d7c  /system/bin/app_process

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this error?